# how to start different activities with one background service

Tags: android, service, asynchronous, android-activity

I'm new to Android and I'm stuck on a conception problem.
I have an application with several activities, some of those activities are critical and require the user to be logged in a webApp.

When the user clicks a button to reach one of those critical activities, I call a background Service which ask if the user is still connected to the webApp (not timeout). If the user is logged in, the activity is started, otherwise a dialog pops up and ask for username and password. The problem is that there is several protected activities, and I want to use the same service to do the verification. The way I do it for the moment works but it's kind of kludgy.

```
    public class A_Activity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        setButtonClickListener();
    }

    private void setButtonClickListener() {

        button_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                Intent intentCall = new Intent(context,com.them.cp.ConnexionManagerService.class);
                intentCall.putExtra("WHO_IS_CALLED","FIRST_ACTIVITY");
                context.startService(intentCall);                   
            }
        });

        button_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentCall = new Intent(context,com.them.cp.ConnexionManagerService.class);
                intentCall.putExtra("WHO_IS_CALLED","SECOND_ACTIVITY");
                context.startService(intentCall);       
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my service

```
    public class ConnexionManagerService extends Service{
    public class IsConnectedAsync extends AsyncTask<String , Void, Void>{
        protected Void doInBackground(String... whoIsCalled) {
            String redirectedURL = getRedirectedURL();
            if(redirectedURL.equalsIgnoreCase(IF_NOT_CONNECTED_URL)){
                if(whoIsCalled[0].equalsIgnoreCase("FIRST_ACTIVITY")){
                    Intent trueIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FirstActivity.class);
                    trueIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplication().startActivity(trueIntent);
                }
                else if(whoIsCalled[0].equalsIgnoreCase("SECOND_ACTIVITY")){
                    Intent trueIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    trueIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplication().startActivity(trueIntent);
                }       
            }
            else{
                Intent falseIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PopUpLoginActivity.class);
                falseIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(falseIntent);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("service onCreate", "onCreate");
     }

     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    String whoIsCalled = intent.getStringExtra("WHO_IS_CALLED");
    new IsConnectedAsync().execute(whoIsCalled);        
    return START_STICKY;
     }

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
     }
 }
```

with my little knowledge I wish i could just send an intent, but it seems that it's not possible as it's not the UI thread.

**My question is: What can I do to make this service more generic ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use the same service to do the verification.

If you don't destroy the service it will be the same service object. If an activity which started your service finishes or stops the service it could be destroyed if it was the unique activity that started the service. If you want to ensure that the service reminds on background start it on you application class (extending Application) and in each activity you need. When an activity stops the service or finishes the service will not be destroyed because your application class is still connected.

EDIT:

To avoid write putExtra again and again:

```
public class StartOrder1 extends Intent {

     public StartOrder(Context ctx, String activity_name){
           super(ctx, ServiceName.class);
           if(activity_name != null)
                super.putExtra("WHO", activity_name);
           else
                super.putExtra("WHO", "UNKNOWN");
     }

     public String getWho(){
           reurn.getIntExtra("WHO");
     }
}
```

To start it:

```
this.startService(new StartOrder1(this, "My activity name"));
```

The best solution:

```
public class StartOrder2 extends Intent {

     public StartOrder(Activity a){
           super(a, ServiceName.class);
           super.putExtra("WHO", a.toString());
     }

     public String getWho(){
           reurn.getIntExtra("WHO");
     }
}
```

And you can override toString method in each Activity passing the activity name, class name, whatever you want. Then when you start an intent:

```
this.startService(new StartOrder2(this));
```

Or extends Activity with this utility:

```
public class EnhancedActivity extends Activity{

     protected startMyService(String name){
          Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
          i.putExtra("who", name);
          startService(i);
     }
}
```

And call it on your final activity

```
[...]
super.startMyService("activity_name");
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know that it will be the same service object. let me clarify my question. I would like to know how to improve the code to be able to pass something in parameters to be able to use it without passing WHO_IS_CALLED with an intent

Comment: ... ok if you dont want to add these information just make your customs Intents.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me alot. But I finally found a way to simplify what I was doing by using fragment, which made my activities architecture way more efficient.